# Object oriented design pattern for parsing json files

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have sets of json files, each set having a different structure. Each json structure has three things, either it's a leaf or an array or someOtherStructure. I want to write a generic parser which could parse a json for all sets of json files based on the above mentioned 3 structures.

Can anyone suggest an Object oriented design pattern for the above case.

Comment: And using [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome) is not an option?

Comment: The first rule of good design is to not re-invent the wheel. So unless this isn't some kind of "homework" activity, the best design choice is to pick an existing library that does JSON parsing for you.

Comment: Parsing is not an issue.I have code ready for what to do if its a leaf or if its a Array and if its some other structure.What design pattern to be applied is unknown.You can though suggest the one for jackson

Comment: OO design patterns have a context that is an OO problem, usually relating to extendability, maintainability, coupling, cohesion, etc. You've described a problem that is parsing of three kinds of structures. I'm not seeing where OO design patterns fit in.

Comment: Like for example , i know i have basically three structures and hence three ways to parse these structure .So  I can use Strategy design pattern .

Answer (score 1):

What I have done in my project

- Leafs are defined in `DTO` class which you want to convert to `JSON`
- Define new class for any other array or other structure, and declare is object in the `DTO`

Hence, your `DTO` will have only leafs and structure like arrary or objects which further may contain leaf or some other structure.

You can use `com.google.gson.Gson` or other similar library to convert the `object` into `json`